# Url Routing in Asp.Net 4.0 (Different Pages with same RouteUrl)

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

*I have two pages "Product.aspx" & "Category.aspx".With URL Routing I want to change URL of the pages.*

This is my code:

**URLRoute.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{     
   routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapPageRoute("Product", "{CategoryName}/{ProductName}","~/Product.aspx");
   routes.MapPageRoute("Category", "Category/{CategoryName}", "~/Category.aspx");
}
```

when I am using this code

```
<a href="Mobile/Samsung"> Go To Product.aspx Page </a>
<a href="Category/Mobile"> Go To Category.aspx Page </a>
```

both Time it is redirecting on Product.aspx page while it should be go different pages.

Note : URL must be like this

for Product.aspx Page : www.example.com/Mobile/Samsung
here Mobile is category name and samsung is product name (both are dynamic).

for Category.aspx Page : www.example.com/category/Mobile
here category is static category name and mobile is category name(category name dynamic).

Comment: Just switch the order first: the `MapPageRoute` for Category and then the one for the Product. When `ASP.NET` tries to match a route it starts with the first and continues till it finds a match. In your case `{CategoryName}/{ProductName}` will always match both routes and it will never go to the category route.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you so much.

Comment: routes.MapPageRoute("Blog", "{BlogName}-{BlogID}", "~/AllBlog.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Tour", "{TourName}", "~/AllTour.aspx");

in this case both page are redirecting on AllBlog.aspx but I need blog on AllBlog.aspx and tour on AllTour.aspx page.

Note : I do not want directory like blog/blogname.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters in routing. `Category/Mobile` matches `{CategoryName}/{ProductName}` (with a value of "Category" for `CategoryName`).

Change

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Product", "{CategoryName}/{ProductName}","~/Product.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Category", "Category/{CategoryName}", "~/Category.aspx");
```

to

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Category", "Category/{CategoryName}", "~/Category.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Product", "{CategoryName}/{ProductName}","~/Product.aspx");
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: routes.MapPageRoute("Blog", "{BlogName}-{BlogID}", "~/AllBlog.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Tour", "{TourName}", "~/AllTour.aspx");

in this case both page are redirecting on AllBlog.aspx but I need blog on AllBlog.aspx and tour on AllTour.aspx page.

Note : I do not want directory like blog/blogname.